# checkbox population in salesforce whenever a docusign document is signed

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to have a checkbox populated in Salesforce, whenever a docusign document associated with the account is signed?

A user has the option to sign the docusign or check a box (stating - 'No Signature required"), if his signature is already on file.

Its whenever he signs the document that we need another checkbox in salesforce to be populated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can accomplish this through a Salesforce Trigger.  See this similar question that was asked not too long ago:

[docusign update parent field on complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30361238/docusign-update-parent-field-on-complete)

That question is regarding updating a picklist in SFDC instead of a checkbox, but I think the logic will be the same.  And there's sample code for the Trigger.